# select minimum value from three different columns oracle

Tags: oracle, min

I have three tables (IDENTIFIER, LOCGRP, AFFILIATION) and they are joined by a column (`id`). They each have "START_DT" columns, and I want the minimum of those columns. Further, I need to select the minimum start date of the minimums for each id across the columns. The SQL I'm using to illustrate is:

```
SELECT id, min(min_i_start, min_lg_start, min_af_start) AS min_start
FROM (
    SELECT 
        i.id
        , min(i.START_DT) AS min_i_start
        , min(lg.START_DT) AS min_lg_start
        , min(af.START_DT) AS min_af_start
    FROM IDENTIFIER i
    INNER JOIN LOCGRP lg ON lg.id = i.id
    INNER JOIN AFFILIATION af ON af.id = i.id
    GROUP BY i.id
)
```

Of course, I knew this wouldn't work because `min()` is an aggregate function in Oracle, so it gives `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments`. But it illustrates my objective: to get the minimum value from across three columns.

To restate: the inner subquery selects three minimum dates for each record. I would like to further select the minimum of the minimums (one value) for each record.

SQL fiddle to illustrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9cf9d9/2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `MIN`, but `LEAST`:

```
least(min_i_start, min_lg_start, min_af_start)
```